# Are there any half-man half-beast creatures in Rig Veda?

Tags: rig-veda

I think these conceptions occur only in Puranas.

Comment: Garuda is quite humanoid-beast creature, in yajur Veda there is narsimhan and danti, kamdhenu is shown with a female head, there are other beings too.

Comment: @AnubhavJha where exactly in Yajurveda Narasimhan mention?

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda प्र तद्विष्णु: स्तवते वीर्येण मृगो न भीमः कुचरो गिरिष्ठाः।
यस्योरुषु त्रिषु विक्रमणेष्वधिक्षियान्ति भुवनानि विश्वा ।।5.20।।

Pra TadVishnuhu Stavate Viryena Mrugo Na Bhima Kucharo Girishtha

YasyoRushu Trishu VikramNeShawaDhiKshiYanti Buvanani Vishwa

Roaming around the earth in fiearc avatars like Lion etc. Residing on mountains , all-pervading Vishnu is highly adorable through his Manhood (Bravery). All the lokas resides under the three giant strides of him. Vishnu deva is praised here as thus.Yajurveda Samhita 5.20

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda रुद्रो रुद्रश्च दन्तिश्च नन्दिः षण्मुख एव च ।
गरुडो ब्रह्मा विष्णुश्च नारसिहंस्तथैव च ।।
rudro rudrascha dantischa nandi sanmukha eva cha |
garudo brahma vishnuscha narsimhastathaiva cha ||  [Yajurveda Taitteriya Aranyaka 10.1.15]

The names of God mentioned are:
Rudra, Danti, Nandi, Shanmukha, Garuda, Brahma, Vishnu, Narsimha, there are other mentions too.

Comment: @S K: An ivory sculpture dating back to 35,000 to 40,000 years was found in Germany in 1939. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion-man).  If a sculpture of that old period had existed, a civilisation, which might have seen/believed such figure, should have existed during 35,000 years back in that area.